# Looking for canonical Q/A - BM-800 NW-700 NW-800

Tags: discussion

We've had a few questions on these cheap Chinese mics - all of which seem to be the same thing in various colours & with various labels. - BM-800 NW-700 NW-800

The question is always pretty much the same thing...

- I bought one & it sounds like *poo*, how do I fix it?

The answer is always the same thing too...

- Get a cheap USB pre-amp with phantom power & a male>female XLR cable.

Could we nominate one as the best [not necessarily oldest] start-point to make canonical & then close all the others as dupes against that one?

Ones I've found so far...

[I bought a Floureon BM-800, and neweer 48v phantom power, but still no sound?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/43014/i-bought-a-floureon-bm-800-and-neweer-48v-phantom-power-but-still-no-sound)

[BM-800 Condenser Mic Not Working in Windows 10 Acer Laptop](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/40017/bm-800-condenser-mic-not-working-in-windows-10-acer-laptop)

[I have a BM 800 Mic that isnt working?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/40605/i-have-a-bm-800-mic-that-isnt-working)

[NW-700 Sound issue](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/41320/nw-700-sound-issue?s=1|36.9401)

[Buzzing noise with Taffware BM 700 condenser microphone](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/40862/buzzing-noise-with-taffware-bm-700-condenser-microphone)

The latest is [Buzzing/Hissing issues](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44184/buzzing-hissing-issues) which doesn't have the best question but may have the easiest to understand answer for newbies.

If we can pick a best question - or even set up a brand new one covering the obvious for someone new to the field & then drop a more finely-honed version of that answer into it, that might be the solution.

Suggestions?
Obviously, we need one that Google can easily find.

BTW, my answer is based on empiricism. I bought one of these things for a tenner on eBay & tested it. They're actually surprisingly not appalling for a tenner, though I'm not going to be swapping out my U87 any time soon ;)

Comment: of those, I think either the BM-800 condenser question, or the one we closed the NW-700 sound issue Q as a dupe of: https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/37504/7016